# any script/code/way to read files of iPhone through a mac/pc

Tags: iphone, file

I would like to know if there is any way (thru any sorta code) to access application directories of apps deployed on iPhone/iPad, when plugged to a mac/pc, just like how iPhoneExplorer does it!!

Comment: Synching iPhone apps on mac using iTunes, it is the best way so far

Comment: @MayurBirari not exactly if you want to do it programmatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. (If there wasn't, how could iTunes and iPhoneExplorer do it?)

You can use the MobileDevice library (present both on OS X and on Windows). It's a private library using the C language, but reverse engineered header files are available (for example, [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library).)

Comment: +1 (cant do it cos i have less than 15 reps :(.. ) anyways, please point me to a good resource/tutorial related to this..

Comment: @ocelot Check the link I provided, there's a self-documented header file :) Btw, you could accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to open iTunes and browse to your device. In the list of apps with the iOS Home Screen style view, there is a section at the bottom to select an Application, and manage it's Documents storage folder.

You do not need to sync in order to view up-to-date information in this screen. You are immediately able to save the data out of the app into a location on your computer.

[image]

Please read the blog [How integrate itunes file sharing with your ios app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) for more detail.